# How to avoid ahead of desturction in derived class?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I launched a thread in based thread. There is a pure virtual function called in this thread.
I implement it in the derived class.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
struct Base {
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> th;
  virtual void foo() = 0;
  void bar() { 
    th = std::make_unique<std::thread>(
      [this](){
        foo();
      }
    );
  }
  virtual ~Base(){
    th->join();
  }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
  virtual void foo() override {
    std::cout << "impl in derived" << std::endl;
  }
};
int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.bar();
  return 0;
}
```

However, in these codes, the derived object will decontruct before the base object.

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How to control the destruction order in this situation?

Comment: Construction: base -> derived. Destruction: derived -> base. Construction: field 1, field 2, field 3. Destruction: field 3, field 2, field 1

Comment: This is essentially a race condition. You call method of the class in one thread and destroy this class in another. Either introduce some synchronization primitives or create a copy of the class in another thread (whatever is more appropriate).

Comment: Do you really need inheritance?

Comment: You can't control the destruction order, since the standard specifies that derived class destructor is called before base class destructor (the reverse of construction order, which is also fully specified).  Either `Base::bar()` needs to join, or you need to provide some other function that can be called by `main()` to join after calling `d.bar()`.  A better approach would be for `Derived` to contain a member of `Base` (rather than inheriting from it) so `Derived`s destructor can explicitly join the thread before completing.

Comment: It's not the problem of destruction order. You *should* control the lifetime of the object. Especially when you're passing the object to another thread.

Comment: In this situation, only the bar() function is different in all derived classes. So I want to launch the thread in base class. I don't want to join the thread each time in derived class. That's the reason why I join the thread in base class.

Comment: Then, as I said, don't use inheritance.  Make `Derived` (with an appropriate name) manage an instance of `Base`.   That way it can appropriately manage the order of joining and the lifetime of objects (which your approach with inheritance cannot do).  There are various ways to then inherit from `Derived` (not `Base`) to provide virtual functions and overrides.

Comment: "*In this situation, only the bar() function is different in all derived classes.*" Doesn't sound like a reason for using a thread. You may need to elaborate on your use case.

Comment: @LouisGo This is only a short reproduce of my project. The bar() function is a consuming function which takes data from a concurrent queue.

Comment: Then you should join the thread (and cancel the operation) when an object is destructed. It's RAII. Or how do you assure whether `this` is destructed?

Comment: Like @Peter said, _inheritance_ does not apply here. Inheritance is very powerful mechanism, but it is not a silver bullet. Use encapsulation instead. In case if you want to create a thread that polls the queue and you cannot control the Queue life time, wrap the queue by `shared_ptr` and pass the lambda with shared_ptr<Queue> into the Base.

Answer (score 5):

This is a concurrency problem, and what happens is undefined behavior. It is entirely possible that if you build a different configuration (for example, switch from Debug to Release build) the application will break differently.

Concretely, I believe that when main finishes execution and goes out of scope, your thread is just started. This calls all destructions, which ends up (in your implementation) with foo pointing to the base class implementation (at the end of the derived destructor) followed by main being blocked in the base destructor - in the call to join.

How to fix:

move the join in a separate function and call it explicitly:

```
struct Base {
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> th;
  virtual void foo() = 0;
  void bar() { 
    th = std::make_unique<std::thread>(
      [this](){
        foo();
      }
    );
  }
  virtual ~Base() = default;

  void join() { th->join(); }
};

int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.bar();
  d.join(); // prevent the destruction of the derived part
            // and main blocking before completing the base
            // destructor execution.
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Simplified](https://godbolt.org/z/nvEvhdGP5)